# Why aren't the pillars of Gringotts Bank straight?

Tags: harry-potter

Hagrid points his finger towards Gringotts Bank when Harry questions him about money:

[image: The front of Gringotts showing the wonky pillars]

Why aren't the pillars of Gringotts Bank straight?

Comment: Going by the movies, every structure in Diagon Alley (and The Leaky Cauldron too for that matter) is old, has odd angles and is slightly askew. It seems that similar could be said of many structures in the wizarding world.

Comment: Because whimsy...

Comment: https://www.housebeautiful.com/design-inspiration/real-estate/g2526/drunk-houses/?slide=1

Comment: related https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73282/why-is-diagon-alley-named-that-way

Comment: It's obvious but probably worth stating here that Diagon Alley is likely a play on "diagonally".

Comment: Because it's filled with crooked bankers.

Comment: For reference, the text which describes Gringotts in Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone can be found here (page 51) http://www.passuneb.com/elibrary/ebooks/Harry%20Potter%20and%20The%20Sorcerer%E2%80%99s%20Stone.pdf - The only words describing the exterior are: "They had reached a snowy white building that towered over the other little shops. Standing beside its burnished bronze doors..."

Comment: @Valorum, Cute pun, but of course the reason why Wizards entrust their treasure to Gringotts is because the goblins are far more worthy of that trust than are humans. The goblins don't like humans, and their customs and values are strange to humans, but they are absolutely dependable.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Damn! As a French, I was reading Alley as "Allay", and didn't make the link :(

Comment: @SolomonSlow except Griphook?

Comment: @Valorum I feel like "Because whimsy" could be the answer to almost every "why" question in the Harry Potter franchise...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - I must confess to having made the comment more than once, along with "***Because he's a schmuck"*** and "***Is the answer midi-chlorians?"***. Some jokes just keep being funny, imho.

Comment: @Ruslan, Touché. Of course, there are exceptions to every rule, and anybody who gets mixed up in the affairs of Harry Potter is going to find themselves in some exceptional situations.

Comment: @Valorum "because magic" and "because of the force" are pretty standard go-tos.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This was an intentional device used by the makers of the film/s to create an other-worldy look and feel to the street, while still respecting that it's based in London.

> “Diagon Alley was one of the first sets we created for Harry Potter
> and the Sorcerer’s Stone,” recalls Stuart Craig. “We started with the
> notion of a Dickensian-type street.” During his research of the time
> period, Craig noted that buildings had an interesting structural
> inclination. **“Very, very early Victorian architecture had this
> gravity-defying lean. So we began to explore the idea of architecture
> that was leaning so much it would appear to be falling over."**
>
> He also
> added elements of Tudor, Georgian, and Queen Anne styles for a unique
> architectural mash-up. Director Chris Columbus and Stuart Craig then
> scouted the London streets, searching for a practical location to film
> Diagon Alley. “We hoped there were still places that actually looked
> like that Dickensian world existing somewhere in London," explains
> Columbus, “but there are very few. And if a place did look like that,
> there would also be something modern there—a phone booth or a grocery
> store. We could have tried to work around those, but in order to
> really have the complete idea, we realized we’d have to build it.”
>
> **Craig felt that the wizarding world wouldn’t be overly concerned with
> imperfections, and so no one would mind buildings that seemed to be
> holding one another up: “We wanted crumbling, ancient dereliction.
> Nothing too smart or done up. It’s as full of character as we could
> possibly make it."** Chris Columbus wanted the street to feel not only
> as if it had been there for hundreds of years but “as if it goes on
> forever."
>
> <sub><sup>*[Harry Potter: Magical Places from the Films: Hogwarts, Diagon Alley, and Beyond](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Harry_Potter:_Magical_Places_from_the_Films:_Hogwarts,_Diagon_Alley,_and_Beyond)*</sup></sub>

Comment: https://www.flickr.com/photos/bazrichardson/13897357782 For anyone who doubts 

Comment: Closely related to the technique of [Dutch angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_angle) for creating a sense of alienation and disorientation, although in this case it's the set and/or the CGI that's skewed, rather than the camera.